# Using Second Person Plural When Referring to a Business

Tags: vocabulario

If I was in a store and wanted to know if they had apples would I say to the clerk, 'tiene manzanas' or 'tienen manzanas'? I suspect the former although I'm not asking if he personnally has apples but rather does the store where he is working has them. I suppose in the southern United states, one might ask 'do you all have apples'.

### Update

To clarify a little, I'm more interested in the conjugate than the specific question. That is, when asking a representative of a business what the business has for sale or what services it offers do you use the singular or plural conjugate?

Comment: Well, we'd say "do **y'all** have apples?" :-)

Comment: I was just going to mention the same: In English, we use the plural... *Do you [guys] sell ice here?*

Comment: What is a conjugate? Do you mean how the verb should be conjugated? In the singular or plural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When asking a representative of a business what the business has for
>   sale or what services it offers do you use the singular or plural
>   conjugate?

I use plural conjugate for sale and also for services. I agree @ferdoqui: I would use the singular only in a small shop that may be run by a unique person.

En general:

- ¿Aquí alquilan coches?
- ¿Tienen pantalones azules de mi talla?

En un negocio unipersonal:

- ¿Alquila (usted) coches?
- ¿Tiene pantalones azules de mi talla?

In case of doubt I use plural conjugate.

Answer (score 3):

In general you assume you are referring to the company instead of the clerk itself. Thus, to me it is more common to use the plural:

> ¿Tienen manzanas?

You would use the singular "¿Tiene manzanas?" if you were in a small shop that may be run by a unique person.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to ask is: *¿le quedan manzanas?* (This implies that you know the market actually has apples, but you want to know if they have as much as you want.)

---

If you are refering to two or more people, you can ask *¿tienen manzanas?*
If it's just one person, ask *¿tiene manzanas?*

Comment: taken together, yours and Forest's answers seem to be complete. In any case — we refer to the store not the teller, making the verb plural.

Comment: The first part alone is worth a vote because it complements all other answers. But I have to add that we would use plural even if when talking to a single person, @Ra_'s answer has a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually ask: ¿Se venden manzanas?

Asking *si alguien tiene algo* does really sound like you're asking if they/that person personally has the item.

Comment: I wouldn't. If I go to the grocery, I don't want to know whether they sell apples or not (I assume they do); I want to know if they have some right now. Hence, *¿Tiene(n) manzanas?*

Comment: I would never ask ¿Se venden ...? Somebody may laugh at me if I would. E.g. I enter in a store where they sell fruits and ask  —¿Se venden manzanas? — No amigo, vendemos conejos ¿Cuántos quiere?

Answer (score 0):

Question:
If I was in a store and wanted to know if they **had apples** would I say to the clerk, 'tiene manzanas' or 'tienen manzanas'?

Answer: **It depends**.

tiene there means tiene Ud. [third person singular]

tienen there means tienen Uds. [third person plural]

The usted form is polite everywhere. So, it depends on whether your "you" is plural (you, the store **employees**) or singular (you, the store **employee).

**However**, in Spain, I would probably say to a **young** clerk, ¿ Tienes manzanas? singular, referring to that one employee. Or ¿ Tenéis manzanas?, the plural if referring to the employees as a whole.